# Socket IO - server not connecting with my react client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I've been breaking my head trying to connect my client to server using socket.io but to no avail. My server is in node and client is written in react. It does not showing in my server when a user connects or disconnects. Here is my code -

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')
const cors = require('cors')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const router = require('./router')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

app.use(cors())
app.use(router)

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User has connected.')
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("User has disconnected.")
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Client(React):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import queryString from 'query-string'
import io from "socket.io-client"

import './chat.styles.css'

let socket

const Chat = ({location}) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [room, setRoom] = useState('')
    const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000/'

    useEffect(() => {
        const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

        socket = io(ENDPOINT)

        setRoom(room)
        setName(name)

      }, [ENDPOINT, location.search])

    return (
        <div className='chat'>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Comment: Are you sure they connect successfully? Check your browser's "Console" for any errors. You may have CSRF problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error.
In the server code i accidentally put

```
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

instead of

```
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: I have the  same error with the same code , Do you know any way how can I solve it , the server is not getting the connection from the frontend , nothin is consoled and it console ERR Unsafe Port

Comment: yeah as mentioned in my answer I put app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)) instead of server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))